# Flask model with enum error causing TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I am creating a Flask model field with enum values linking to `class` like so.

```
class ValueTypes(enum.Enum):
    min = 'min'
    max = 'max'
    optimum = 'opt'

class Param(db.Model):
    # ...
    type = db.Column(db.Enum(ValueTypes), default=ValueTypes.optimum)
```

And receiving the error like so:

```
...
  File "/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1316, in <genexpr>
length = max(len(x) for x in self.enums)
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

I want a field that is filtered by those enum values on a model layer.
How to do it properly? OR why error is happening? OR Have I missed something in syntax maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Param(db.Model):
    # ...
    type = db.Column(db.Enum("min", "max", "opt", name="ValueTypes"), default="opt")
```

Comment: it raises sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: PostgreSQL ENUM type requires a name.

Comment: @AmirShabani https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254775/error-when-running-migrations-sqlalchemy-exc-compileerror-postgresql-enum-type

Comment: some explanation would be useful instead of just throwing a piece of code

Comment: I've been going in circles with various AIs trying to figure out the problem. This fixed it (though it took me quite a bit of digging to find it even after abandoning the AI route). Thank you.